# How can I open a dataset in bigquery that have dropdown menu and this consist date

Tags: python, google-bigquery

In bigquery sample dataset, I found that data table: `google_analytics_sample`. And that table consist of dropdown menu by date time.

[image]

When I click the dropdown menu, I can see the dates.

[image]

So, i have few questions:
1. How can I open the dataset like that? 
2. Is there way to open it with python-api? 
3. And also is the dataset a partitioned table?

Answer (score 0):

The dataset is not a partitioned table, it is a date-sharded dataset: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#dt_partition_shard

In the documentation I shared above you can also see how to create them.

> You can shard tables using a time-based naming approach such as
>   `[PREFIX]_YYYYMMDD`

However, **it is recommended to use partitioned tables instead of using date-sharded** ones: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-communication#avoid_tables_sharded_by_date

When you create date-sharded tables, each one of the tables will have its own schema and metadata, while partitioned tables will share them.